# Upgrading Ram on macbook pro mid 2010

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

[image]

Hello,
I would like to upgrade my macbook pro mid 2010's ram so it could run faster. I'm going to be a student next year so i'd like to lower the costs as much as I can.

what would be the maximum ram that i can upgrade it to?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Max memory for that model Mac is 8GB. You should also consider replacing the spinning Hard Disk with a Solid State Drive (SSD). It would be like
getting a brand new Mac.

Comment: +1 for SSD advice. I did both for my daughters MacBook, and the SSD made far more difference than the RAM bump.